# Insert Statement Take too long to insert - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, insert

Following Insert query taking too long time to insert :

> Query_time: 14.798782  Lock_time: 0.000062 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0

```
SET timestamp=1523459374;
insert into patient_last_examined
     (patient_id,operator_id,section_name,created_date,status,save_or_review)
VALUES  ('227350','72','Allergies','2018-04-11 11:09:20','0','1');
```

Table have 17k records before insertion and
Total Column : 13
Index Columns : id (PK), patient_id,section_name
Db Engine : Inno DB

Can you please suggest how to increase the performance?
(At `timestamp=1523459374`, 15-20 more insertion take place for other tables)

Comment: Please post A) SHOW CREATE TABLE patient_last_examined;  and B) SHOW INDEX FROM patient_last_examined;   Is query_time typically ~14 seconds to insert ONE row?

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post here or in pastebin.com 
RAM on your Host server 
complete my.cnf-ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete MySQLTuner.com  report if readily available
Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop   OR  top for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
free -m  for a linux/unix free memory report 
for analysis of your configuration.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Please find https://pastebin.com/07PuHnVe

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post here or in pastebin.com RAM available on your Host server?  OS you are using?  Complete my.cnf-ini Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C) complete MySQLTuner.com report if readily available Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, free -m for a linux/unix free memory report for analysis of your configuration.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Sorry I can't share SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES and MySQLTuner report

Comment: With the available information, I will do what I can for you.  Suggestions will be here by Monday morning.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: @ShilpaGarg - Why can't you share the `VARIABLES`?  Except perhaps for the `hostname`, I can't think of any setting that could be the least bit sensitive.

Comment: @RickJames my administrator doesn't allow me to share these variable values

Comment: @ShilpaGarg - Can you pose my question to him?

Comment: @RickJames, Ok I will. Can you please suggest something on my query expect than using these variables? Moreover, this single query not taking too much time to insert but at same timestamp some more actions performing on database then it is taking long than expected time

Comment: Is the Query cache turned on?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, Query cache is on

Answer (score 1):

The table is **MyISAM**

You should really switch to InnoDB.

If something taking 14.7 (or more) seconds touches that table, then writes can occur until it finishes.  The "something" could be `mysqldump`, a complex `SELECT`, etc, etc.

InnoDB avoids most such lengthy hangs.

Comment: ok i will try with this

Comment: I am sorry, Table is already InnoDB

Comment: @ShilpaGarg -- the pastbin said MyISAM for `patient_last_examined` ???

Comment: I am sorry for inconvenience, I have changed it already with InnoDB on another Server. But by mistaken provided you script of old server. And moreover I am facing this issue with InnoDB server

Comment: Do the length hangs happen with InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

```
Table_open_cache_hits 53758
Table_open_cache_misses 2768
Table_open_cache_overflows 870
```

What is the value of `table_open_cache`?  It is possibly too small.  And check `ulimit` in the OS.

Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%'` -- I suspect you have a large cache, and the "pruning" of it (which happens on `INSERTs`) is clogging the system.

How much RAM do you have?  Is there any swapping?

The `STATUS` has several hints of slow queries.  What other slow queries are there?  Especially touching the same table.

Comment: I will try to provide you these details by EOD

Answer (score 0):

You just try these three steps to fast insertion:

- InnoDB supports transaction If you have multiple insertion then use transaction in your insertion.

  ```
  START TRANSACTION
  Your insertion query
  Commit;
  ```

  As, innoDB has to do a commit after each insertion statement which slowed down the insertion process.
- If using Transaction does not solve your problem then check `innodb_fush_log_at_trx_commit`.

Default setting of InnoDB is `innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=1`
In this case, InnoDB will write the log buffer to transaction log and flush to durable storage for every transaction. 
Here, for all transaction commit, InnoDB will write to log and then write to disk, if in case the slower disk storage, it will badly impact the performance, i.e. the number of InnoDB transaction per second will be reduced.;

So, if you want fast insertion then set

```
 innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0;  
 sync_binlog=0;
```

When you set `innodb_flush_log_trx_at_commit=0`, InnoDB will write the modified data (in InnoDB Buffer Pool) to log file (ib_logfile) and flush the log file (write to disk) every second, but it will not do anything at transaction commit. So, your insertion will be fast.
Here, in case if there is a power failure or system crash, all the unflushed data will not be recoverable, since, it is not either written to log file or stored disk.

Or you may set

```
 innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

When you set `innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 2`, InnoDB will write the log buffer to log file at every commit, but don't write data to disk. InnoDB flushes data once in every second.
Option 2, even if there is a power failure or system crash, data will be available in log file and can be recoverable.

- InnoDB is very RAM dependent, you might find better result if you tweak the settings.
  What's your innodb buffer-pool size?
       Make sure you've set it to about 75% of your RAM.